# Doctrine 2: Custom Foreign Key names

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys

is there any way to customize the foreign key in Doctrine 2?

My Problem is, that I get an error when I try to clone a table.
Because when I clone the tables, the foreign keys are cloned too and the names are the same which results in an error.